# Measurability of diagonal implies measurability of individual points

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Kingman (1973) writes on Page 11:

*Suppose that $S$ is a measurable space. ... by making the weak assumption that the diagonal $D = \{(x, y); x = y\}$ is measurable in the product space $S\times S$. This automatically implies that every singleton set $\{x\}$ in $S$ is measurable.*

Formally, why is the measurability of individual points in $S$ automatically implied by the measurability of the diagonal in $S\times S$?

Comment: Fubini-Tonelli would give that $\{ x \}$ is measurable for a.e. $x$...

Comment: @DanielSchepler I guess Fubini-Tonelli might be an overkill here...

Comment: @DanielSchepler, if $\mu$ were a $\sigma$-finite measure on $S$, then Fubini-Tonelli would imply $\{x\}$ is $\mu$-measurable (i.e. in a possibly larger $\sigma$-algebra than the original).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For definiteness, let $(S,\mathcal{A})$ be a measure space and $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A}$, the corresponding product $\sigma$-algebra on $S \times S$.  Recall that if $E \in \mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A}$ and $y \in S$, then the set $E_{y} \subseteq S$ defined by
$$E_{y} = \{x \in S \, \mid \, (x,y) \in E\}$$
satisfies $E_{y} \in \mathcal{A}$.  Indeed, if we let $\mathcal{G}$ denote the family
$$\mathcal{G} = \{E \subseteq S \times S \, \mid \, E_{y} \in \mathcal{A}\},$$
then $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $S \times S$ containing the collection of measurable rectangles $\{A \times B \, \mid \, A,B \in \mathcal{A}\}$.  Therefore, $\mathcal{A} \otimes \mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathcal{G}$, proving the claim.

Now if $\Delta \subseteq S \times S$ is the diagonal, then $\Delta_{y} = \{y\}$.  Therefore,
$$\forall y \in S \quad \{y\} = \Delta_{y} \in \mathcal{A}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the clean and rigorous proof!